# Mongoose Populate Virtuals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How to populate array of objects not by _id? I need it because I use "market_hash_name" as id in my project and it's more effectively then use _id:

```js
let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    steamid: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        required: true
    },
    inventory: [{
        market_hash_name: String,
        name: String,
        assetid: {
            type: String
        },
        instanceid: {
            type: String,
            default: '0'
        },
        contextid: {
            type: String,
            default: '2'
        },
        amount: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        },
        ongoing_price_manipulation: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        price: {
            type: Number
        }
    }]
});
```

I used virtuals but only for a separate model and it works:

```js
schema.virtual('item_data', {
    ref: 'Steamlytics',
    localField: 'market_hash_name',
    foreignField: 'market_hash_name'
});

this.find(query).populate("item_data").exec((err, items) => {});
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: I don't know how to populate array of refs without _id